# Would Building a Waypoint/Colony station in Slip Space be Logical?

Tags: space, physics, space-constructs, travel, wormholes

Definitions:

Slip Space - The area of space separating planes of the universe. Think of the universe as a flat piece of paper. Now imagine this flat piece of paper wrapped into a spherical ball. The surface of the paper is our universe. The area of space in between the separate ends is Slip Space. Only pure energy can exist in Slip Space. The laws of physics don't apply in Slip Space, meaning any matter that enters unprotected is instantly converted into pure energy. This also means that faster than light travel is easily available. You can start accelerating at one end and be at the total other side of the universe in three days.

Slip Gate - A contained singularity drive. Uses anti-matter to create a temporary singularity. This allows people to enter Slip Space. Dangerous to use on or near large bodies such as planets and stars.

X-Suit - Anti-gravity suit worn by people entering Slip Space through a Slip Gate. This stops the Slip Gate singularity drive from crunching the people. The ship must also be outfitted with one.

Infinity Drive - A vital component in space travel. This allows the ship to open up a Slip Hole to exit Slip Space, from inside Slip Space. This also generates a field of energy around the ship, capturing the laws of physics of our universe in a little bubble of energy around the ship. This prevents the ship from disintegrating into pure energy.

Question:

How difficult would it be to build a space station in Slip Space? Would it make more sense to send construction teams and raw materials and build it in Slip Space, or to assemble the massive station in real space and send it into Slip Space? The station would house a hundred million crew and would be used as a forward to alien colonization.

I think I included all the details you need to know to answer, but if I didn't feel free to drop a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: I mistakenly asked this question [twice](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/how-practical-is-building-a-station-in-slip-space) deleted second post. Browser is buggy.

Comment: You say a "Massive" space station, but that's a rather vague description in fiction.  Would it be big enough that it would complicate a slip gate?  You mention that doing them near planets/stars is a bad idea, if the station has sufficient mass you might *have* to build it in Slip Space.

Comment: Building them near stars and planets is only bad because these are essentially miniature black holes. It is obviously dangerous to open a black hole near your home planet or parent star.

Comment: Ok -  I asked because a common theme in FTL travel is that mass distortions negatively effect them, or that it becomes prohibitively expensive as mass increases.  So enough mass = dysfunctional/dangerous FTL.  Wasn't sure if that would apply here, but if it did...

Comment: "The laws of Physics don't apply in Slip Space, meaning any matter that enters unprotected is instantly converted into pure energy." How do you protect something, using engineering, where the laws of physics don't apply? Do my biological processes even still function there?

Comment: @Samuel In my hypothetical scenario, we have mastered the manipulation of energy, therefore we can create a "shield" of energy around our ship preserving the laws of physics in this small bubble.

Comment: @DustinJackson But... You said everything in Slip Space is energy, why would more energy protect against that? Also, do you see [this](http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lk6jefb6if1qcvvvlo1_500.gif) when you go the end of this piece of paper?

Comment: @Samuel I do not recall including the tag "reality-check". I do appreciate the effort, though. The energy can accelerate to the speed of light, melting a chunk of the universe to the ship. I dont know how to better explain it than compare it to a piece of paper that is bent into a ball. That is not how it actually looks from the outside (I am pretty sure) but it behaves like that.

Comment: @DustinJackson Ok, fair enough, it's an appropriate description. Reality-check would be a bit different, this was more of a self-consistency-check, because in reality our universe is flat, not curved.

Comment: @Samuel oh the irony! The Earth is flat, not curved.

Comment: @DustinJackson It's not ironic, the [universe is flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe).

Comment: @Samuel I was comparing it to the majority belief in Ancient times. That was ironic and if it turns out in the distant future that the universe is curved around itself it will be pretty ironic.

Comment: I am well aware of the leading theories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume a couple of things.

- Slip Space plots directly and proportionally to real space.
- Since the universe is infinitely large, there is no "edge of the universe".
- Slip Space doesn't have a maximum or minimum speed, so something can be in Slip Space and not move.

If these things are true, then logically it would follow that we would do basically the same thing for Slip Space that we did for real space. Probes, then ships, then a space station. The first space station we sent into orbit was built on earth and assembled in orbit. Most likely that is the way it would happen here.

We can also build things in space. We haven't gotten to this point yet, but I think that we will. It makes sense. If we're going to build starships like in Star Trek, we're going to need to build them in space.

If this is the first of it's kind, and meant to stay in SlipSpace forever, then it would need to be built mostly in real space, and then transported to and assembled in Slip Space. The Slip Gates could then be taken off and sent back to be re-used with some kind of shuttlecraft.

On the other hand, if this colony is meant to drop in and out of Slip Space, dropping off colonists before moving on, then it would probably be best to just build a REALLY big ship.

This next paragraph is about the sustainability of the ship once it gets going. It's not actually answering the question, but it is on topic. I put it in a spoiler so that if you don't want to read my idea, then you don't have to.

> With both of these ideas, you could have some way to bring asteroids, comets, or other useful space debris into Slip Space while in transit and then process it on the go and create the actual colony ships, meant to go off in Slip Space to their destination without the mothership ever stopping or even slowing down. The pro to this is that the mothership could last for a really long time, seeding the stars as it goes. The con is that if you run out of something in between galaxies, you're hosed. But this is also kind of a pro, as there is no need to colonize things in between galaxies.

Back to the question. It really depends a lot on logistics. Can you "fit" a huge ship into Slip Space? What about transporting multiple ships into Slip Space at the same time? What if something goes wrong and one mini black hole slips into another mini black hole - is there suddenly a Slip Space in Slip Space? Is it possible to merge Infinity Drive bubbles?

If the answer to the first and last questions are both "no", then it would be really hard to get a big ship into Slip Space. What could be done is to have a really long but slender ship move really fast so that all of it makes it into the black hole before it collapses. Then, if needed, the ship could un/refold itself in Slip Space.

Logistics is key.

Answer (score 3):

Well first I'm wondering why you would need a space station inside slip-space since it only takes 3 days to get from one side of UNIVERSE to the other.

Second how do you 'navigate' through slip-space, and where would you position it and how would you find the space station.

3rd, why do you need a space station here?

OK, to the actual question, I would expect that creating the space station (at least to a functional level) and then moving it into slip-space would make more sense.  If for no other reason than you should be able to bring the station back into real space should some of the protection systems begin to fail.  As dangerous as space is, it still sounds like a much safer place to have a construction project going on than inside a bubble surrounded by forces trying to tear everything apart.

Comment: *it still sounds like a much safer place to have a construction project going on than inside a bubble surrounded by forces trying to tear everything apart.* ding ding ding, we have a winner.

Comment: Just building the necessary environment for a slipspace building project would probably take more work than building the actual station. And most of *that* work would have to be done in realspace.

Comment: Addressing your wondering as to why we need a station, it is to do several things. 1.) Control and regulate and tax intergalactic travel. 2.) Have a military presence that can give Earth control of colonies easier (e.g. No need to invest huge power into the opening of two slip gates. Now only one slip gate). 3.) Good tourism business.

Comment: Depending on your world: 1) only valid if slip-space is actually "very small" 2) you still have to provide food for your troops, and you have a huge "infinity-drive" working constantly so it may not be worth it. 3)Is there anything to do/see in there? If not some kind of "cruise" may be cheaper.

Comment: I am thinking maybe putting a station around each entry and exit point. Bio farms could grow edible algae rather quickly, and entire sections of the station would be agricultural. Maybe I should have included in question, but energy glows making spectacular light shows.

Comment: @DustinJackson you could have billions of entry and exit points just in this galaxy alone.

Comment: Suitable entry points have to be manually constructed. They tend to be smaller. Since we are the only known species with this tech, we only have to monitor our own portals. We only have a few thousand portals and only a couple hundred earth-like planets (with the rest being created for waypoints and science bases in uninhabitable systems). Therefore you would only really need to tax and regulate the Earth-like planets since most interstellar travel would be directed towards them.

Comment: In that case why not have the stations built into around each gate, that would give full control, and if anyone attacked they would risk damaging the gate as well.  Real space side would be much safer and cheaper to guard against.

Comment: I'd suggest that slipspace stations are necessary in case of slipspace accidents. I'd imagine communication in slipspace to be slippery at best, and if your infinity drive starts failing it'd be good to know there are rescue workers nearby, ready and able to help.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh How can anything be rescued from being "instantly converted into pure energy"? Additionally, with physics no being valid there, it's unclear even visual communications would work.

Comment: @Samuel You're not dead yet, but maybe you're leaking fuel. Or maybe your navigation equipment broke, so you're just lost and don't want to jump out into a star. And I wasn't thinking visual communication, but some sort of sensor equipment should have been invented for these problems.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Ok, well it's all pretty unclear; intentionally unclear, it seems. Hopefully the leaking fuel isn't being converted to pure energy right next to you. That could be uncomfortable.

Comment: One possible use for a Slipspace station might be some kind of Panopticon. If traversing slipspace can take you clear across the universe in no time flat, you may able to use it to perform observations on any location in the universe remotely as well, in which case placing a large space station with the necessary equipment as a kind of Observatory might be effective. If your equipment is necessarily large and complex, you need a lot of people, and now you have a large community living day-to-day in Slipspace.